# How to append b tag on text conditionally?

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

I have this code for pagination and search:

```
return this.props.todos.filter( (todo) => todo.text.toLowerCase().indexOf(this.state.searchText.toLowerCase()) !== -1 ).slice( (currentPage - 1) * pageSize, currentPage * pageSize ).map((todo,todoIndex) => {
          return <Todo
            key={todo.id}
            {...todo} // pass all the todo property
            onClick={() => onTodoClick(todo.id)}
            onTrashClick={() => onDeleteClick(todo.id, todoIndex)}
            handleSelectedTodo = {this._handleSelectedTodo}
            isChecked={this.state.checkedIds.includes(todo.id)}
          />
```

On the Todo component I am thinking of pushing  tag inside the text that matches the searchText state. Something Like this:

```
todo.text.indexOf(this.state.searchText) ? todo.text.split(').push('<b>.....
```

So if some part of the text matches the searchText state, I will push  tag so the result would be like this when `this.state.searchText = 'cde'` and `text = 'abcdefg'`:

```
'a<b>cde</b>fg'
```

Help?

Comment: Just pass needed data with component props and render them in appropriate way in component itself

Comment: I would pass a prop like `isMatched`. Within the Todo component you can do something like:

```
<div>
  {isMatch && <b>{text}</b>}
  {!isMatch && <b>{text}</b>}
</div>
```

Comment: Would really appreciate code for this

Comment: @Skeevs I wanted to bold only part of the text that matches the searchText state, not the whole text

Comment: _I wanted to bold only part of the text that matches the searchText state.._ So what's the problem? Just pass the searching text into component and handle it there using [string manipulation methods](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Text_formatting#Methods_of_String).

Comment: i suggest against using `<b>` , use `<strong>` instead : ` According to the HTML 5 specification, the <b> tag should be used as a LAST resort when no other tag is more appropriate.Important text should be denoted with the <strong> tag`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe something like this ?

```js
const Todo = ({ rSearch, text }) => {
  var strs = text.split(rSearch);
  return (
    <span>
      {strs.map(
        (str, i) =>
          rSearch.test(str) ? <b key={i}>{str}</b> : <span key={i}>{str}</span>
      )}
    </span>
  );
};

class TodoList extends React.Component {
  state = {
    searchText: 'cde'
  };
  render() {
    const { items } = this.props;
    const { searchText } = this.state;
    const rSearch = new RegExp(`(${searchText})`, 'g');
    return (
      <div>
        <input type="text" defaultValue={searchText} />
        <ul>
          {items.map((item, i) =>
            <li key={i}>
              <Todo rSearch={rSearch} text={item.text} />
            </li>
          )}
        </ul>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

const todoItems = [
  {
    text: 'abcdefgh'
  },
  {
    text: 'ijkcdefgh'
  }
];

ReactDOM.render(
  <TodoList items={todoItems} />,
  document.getElementById('root')
);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```